# Any reason an INSERT in a trigger would do nothing?

Tags: advantage-database-server

So I've added the following trigger on a table:

```
INSERT INTO TNQueue (QueuedDate, Action)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ManageLoadOrderTypes');
```

and it doesn't appear to do anything.  I have several other, much more complicated trigger on other tables that all work great.  They all do this sort of insert to this same table, but generally after checking for changes, if the record warrants an insert, decided what data to insert, sub query the __new and __old tables, etc.

The same trigger exists for both AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE.  I've tried with and without _*old/*_new tables and memo data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the Trigger was the table open by other users (or even your user)?

If I remember correctly, if the table did not have any triggers and was opened, any new triggers do not take effect until ALL users close the table.

Comment: Edgar - Tell the other guys that your my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont commit, I believe the change will automatically rollback